# Unexpected format string behavior

Tags: python, c, printf, string-formatting

I just ran into what seemed to me to be bizarre string formatting behavior in python. It turned out to be caused by carriage return characters ('\r') I didn't know were there. Here's an example:

```
>>> text = 'hello\r'
>>> '(SUBJECT "%s")' % (text)
'(SUBJECT "hello\r")'
>>> print '(SUBJECT "%s")' % (text)
")UBJECT "hello
```

I tried the same thing in C (on a couple machines) as a sanity check.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *text = "hello\r";
    printf("(SUBJECT \"%s\")\n", text);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
% ./a.out
")UBJECT "hello
```

Is this desired behavior? If so, can someone explain what is going on?

Comment: "carriage return" is a quaint old fashioned term meaning "go to beginning of line".

Comment: Use "./a.out | od -c" to see what really came out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It (\r) is a carridge return without a linefeed so the cursor moves back to the start of the current line without moving onto a new line and therefore overwriting what is already displayed.

The behaviour depends on your console and whether it interprets CR and LF as individual operations.